# explain call back in example code

Tags: java, callback

I follow the tutorial ([here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html))

But I cannot get it. As I know callback is something which will be called after main thread done. I try to run the example but it is not what I understood.

These are my classes:

*InterestingEvent.java*

```
package callback;

public interface InterestingEvent {
     // This is just a regular method so it can return something or
    // take arguments if you like.
    public void interestingEvent ();
}
```

CallMe.java

```
package callback;

public class CallMe implements InterestingEvent {

    private EventNotifier en; 
    public CallMe ()
    {
    // Create the event notifier and pass ourself to it.
    en = new EventNotifier (this);
    } 
    // Define the actual handler for the event.
    public void interestingEvent ()
    {
    // Wow!  Something really interesting must have occurred!
    // Do something...
        System.out.println("Interesting event method");
    } 


}
```

EventNotifier.java

```
package callback;

public class EventNotifier {
    private InterestingEvent ie;
    private boolean somethingHappened; 
    public EventNotifier (InterestingEvent event)
    {
    // Save the event object for later use.
    ie = event; 
    // Nothing to report yet.
    somethingHappened = true;
    } 
    public void doWork ()
    {
        System.out.println("doWork 1");
    // Check the predicate, which is set elsewhere.
    if (somethingHappened)
        {
        System.out.println("doWork 2");

        // Signal the even by invoking the interface's method.
        ie.interestingEvent ();
        System.out.println("doWork 3");
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterestingEvent ie = new CallMe();
        EventNotifier e = new EventNotifier(ie);
        e.doWork();
        System.out.println("Main flow finish!");
    }
}
```

*Ouput:*

```
doWork 1
doWork 2
Interesting event method
doWork 3
Main flow finish!
```

Main thread was finished at the end of program.

As well as I know, output should be:

```
Main flow finish! -- Main thread should be done first!!!
doWork 1
doWork 2
Interesting event method
doWork 3
```

Anyone please explain the example, what's incorrect?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't see the code where you're printing `Main flow finish!`.

Comment: A callback can be executed at any time. There is no rule saying that it must be executed after the main thread is done. Moreover, your example has only a single thread, so it will simply exit after the main thread is done, nothing else will happen.

Comment: @rgettman oh, sry. I updated system out.

Comment: @yole really? bcoz I thought that callback machanism looks like callback in javascript. If not, callback is not meaningful